# Vertical div inverting H1 color

Tags: javascript, html, css

It is possible to invert the color of a portion of an h1 with a div,  horizontally ? Example shown in the picture.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sure, you can always write code to make that happen. But if your follow up is "cool: can you tell me how I do that?" then it's way too early to post to SO: go out and search for possible ways to do this yourself, first - then _try_ some of those things, and only if after all of that you still get stuck, you might have a good question for posting here.

Comment: I need to learn lot of things about developing and posting on this comunity, I will do a deeper search on the internet . Thank you and I apologize for my question asked too early . Have a great day !

Comment: Protip for future postings: take the [tour], make sure to read through ["what is on-topic"](/help/on-topic) and then make sure to reread ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) every now and then. Those policy articles contain a lot of important information for posting to SO without getting your question closed =)

Comment: I see, I will do this asap . Thanks your for your patience !

Comment: No problem, they probably had a reason closing my question, it's alright anyway . Thanks all of you for your time and I am sory if my question wasted it . Have a great night/day !

Comment: No worries, @AndreiShadowS - your question above was a _great_ question (although quite a tough one!) You have a good evening too.

Comment: Since you posted such a good question @AndreiShadowS (and people who couldn't even attempt to answer it then closed it) I have posted [a CSS-only approach on GitHub](https://github.com/RouninMedia/css-inverse-text-and-background/blob/master/all-in-one-inverse.html). Bear in mind this isn't the only approach - other approaches exist including cloning a node and re-styling the new node via javascript - but I thought you would appreciate a CSS-only approach (using `z-index positioning`, `pseudo-elements` and `clip-path`) where you can examine the CSS source and figure out how it all works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with backdrop-filter

```css
h1 {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  position: relative;
}

h1::after {
  content: "";
  backdrop-filter: invert(100%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped me .

Comment: @AndreiShadowS In the future when you post questions, add basic HTML mark up that you may have so people do not freak out like they did here.

Comment: This is concise and brilliant, @epascarello. I couldn't understand why it wasn't working for me (or why I'd never heard of it) until I realised that [`backdrop-filter` is not yet supported by Firefox](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backdrop-filter).